# How to read a list of words into tuples that include word positions?

Tags: string, algorithm, ocaml

I have a textual file and I would like to write a function that reads this file and returns a list of tuples, where each tuple will consist of the word as string, the word line number as int, and the position of the last character of the word as int. Sample input,

```
example of the first line         
followed by the second line
```

Sample output:

```
[
  ("example",1,8);
  ("of",1,11);
  ("the",1,15);
  ("first",1,21);
  ("line",1,26);
  ("followed",2,13);
  ("by",2,16);
  ("the",2,20);
  ("second",2,27);
  ("line",2,32)
]
```

Comment: How do you define a "line" ? `\n` ?

Comment: I don't understand "last character of the word as int". It might help if you gave a simple input (say two lines) and the desired output. At any event IMHO there seems to be nothing tricky about this at all, it's "just programming".

Comment: As an input, i can have a file with this content for exemple :


```example of the first line
        followed by the second line```
And as output this : 

**[("example",1,8);("of",1,11);("the",1,15);("first",1,21);("line",1,26);("followed",2,13);("by",2,16);("the",2,20);("second",2,27);("line",2,32)]**

Comment: so you meant the _position_ of the last character counting from the beginning of the line, right? And how do you separate lines, with a newline symbol (aka enter, aka `\n`)?

Comment: A line is a real line in a file, line 1 is line one and so on.
So, if i split the string with ```\n``` as argument, i with the line of every substring @Seb

Answer (score 1):

The function that you are looking looks something like this,

```ml
let read filename =
  In_channel.read_lines filename |>
  List.mapi ~f:(fun line data ->
      String.split data ~on:' ' |>
      List.fold_map ~init:0 ~f:(fun pos word ->
          let pos = pos + String.length word in
          pos+1, (word,line+1,pos-1)) |>
      snd) |>
  List.concat
```

Here is how to use it. First install the dependencies,

```
opam install dune stdio merlin
```

Next, setup your project,

```
dune init exe readlines --libs=base,stdio
```

Then open `readlines.ml` in your favorite editor and substitute its contents with the following,

```
open Base
open Stdio

let read filename =
  In_channel.read_lines filename |>
  List.mapi ~f:(fun line data ->
      String.split data ~on:' ' |>
      List.fold_map ~init:0 ~f:(fun pos word ->
          let pos = pos + String.length word in
          pos+1, (word,line+1,pos-1)) |>
      snd) |>
  List.concat

let print =
  List.iter ~f:(fun (line,data,pos) ->
      printf "(%s,%d,%d)\n" line data pos)

let main filename =
  print (read filename)

let () = match Sys.get_argv () with
  | [|_; filename|] -> main filename
  | _ -> failwith "expects one argument: filename"
```

To run and test, create a sample input, e.g. a file named `test.txt`

```
example of the first line
followed by the second line
```

(make sure that the last line is followed by a newline)

Now you can run it,

```
dune exec ./readlines.exe test.txt
```

The result should be the following,

```
(example,1,6)
(of,1,9)
(the,1,13)
(first,1,19)
(line,1,24)
(followed,2,7)
(by,2,10)
(the,2,14)
(second,2,21)
(line,2,26)
```

(Notice, that I am counting positions from 0 not from 1).

You can also run this code interactively in utop, but you would need to install `base` and `stdio` and load them into the interpreter, with

```
#require "base";;
#require "stdio";;
```

If you're not using `utop` but the default OCaml toplevel, you need to also install ocamlfind (`opam install ocamlfind`) and do

```
#use "topfind";;
#require "base";;
#require "stdio";;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just use the standard libraries as String you can do what you want with `String.split_on_char` and some other stuff applied on each line.

 Here is an example on how you could do for the first lien

```ml
let ic = open_in (*your file name*) in 
let first_line = input_line ic in 
let words = String.split_on_char ' ' first_line in
let rec aux accLen = 
  function
  | [] -> []
  | s :: ts -> 
    match s with
    (* empty string means that their were a white space before the split *)
       | "" -> aux (accLen +1) ts
       | s -> let l = accLen + String.length s in (1, s, l) :: aux l ts
in aux 0 words;;
```

As ivg said, you can replace the aux function with a `List.fold_left` :

```ml
let ic = open_in (*your file name*) in 
let first_line = input_line ic in 
let words = String.split_on_char ' ' first_line in
let _, l = List.fold_left (
   fun (accLen, accRes) -> 
       function 
       | "" -> (accLen+1, accRes)
       | s -> let l = accLen + String.length s in (l, (1, s, l) :: accRes)
   ) (0, []) words
in List.rev l;;
```

Comment: it will always print `1` as the line number. It also uses mutable state. The OP wanted to have a list of tuples, not the printout of the file. And it is not even a function so it is not clear how to use it. Consider turning it into a function and remove mutable state (you can use List.fold_left). Then I will happily upvote your answer. No offense that this answer doesn't show OCaml best practices.

Comment: @ivg I didn't want to give the full answer, just a lead to follow. That's why I only convert the first line. Concerning the `List.fold_left`,  I preferred the `aux` because I think it's easier to understand. Finally, I removed the mutable state, which was indeed not a good example. I'll add the fold_left thing if you think it'll be useful

Comment: OK, I don't really think that it is the assignment, sounds more like a coding question. Which I prefer to answer fully to help novice OCaml programmers bootstrapping their code.

Comment: I get your point. I wrote my answer to give some ideas to the asker when you did it in order to provide a full solution to any programmer who would like to perform the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't include the file I/O component, but does properly handle multiple spaces between words, including tabs. Some fun use of `fold_left` to entertain a new OCaml programmer.

```
let words_with_last_index line =
  line ^ " "
  |> String.to_seqi
  |> Seq.fold_left 
       (fun (wspace, cur_word, words) (cur_pos, cur_ch) ->
          match cur_ch with
          | (' ' | '\t') when wspace || cur_pos = 0 -> (true, cur_word, words)
          | ' ' | '\t' -> (true, "", words @ [(cur_word, cur_pos - 1)])
          | ch -> (false, cur_word ^ String.make 1 ch, words))
       (false, "", [])
  |> (fun (_, _, collection) -> collection)
  
let parse_lines text =
  text
  |> String.split_on_char '\n'
  |> List.mapi 
       (fun i line -> 
          line 
          |> words_with_last_index
          |> List.map (fun (word, pos) -> (word, i + 1, pos)))
  |> List.flatten
```